# horizontal list and advanced data grid flex

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, horizontallist

I am trying to use advanced datagrid inside a horizontal list in flex. But I am not able to specify a correct item renderer for it to work. First of all is it even possible to do so? I am getting just a blank table if I use mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid as renderer.

Comment: Is very important how build your object. The object as item of your HorizontalList has an arrayCollection? You want to pass this to your datagrid?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot put them in a scrollable HGroup, and then give each datagrid a 'click' action, so that it is as if they are in a h-list? If I know why you need to do this it will be easier to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override public function set data(value:Object) : void {
            if(value) {
                dg.dataProvider = value;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```